# Lookup tables in Core Data

Tags: core-data, lookup-tables

Core data is not a database and so I am getting confused as to how to create, manage or even implement Lookup tables in core data.

Here is a specific example that relates to my project.

> Staff (1) -> (Many) Talents (1)

The `talents` table consists of:

> TalentSkillName (String)
>
> TalentSkillLevel (int)

But I do not want to keep entering the `TalentSkillName`, so I want to put this information into another, separate table/entity.

But as Core Data is not really a database, I'm getting confused as to what the relationships should look like, or even if Lookup tables should even be stored in core data.

One solution I'm thinking of is to use a PLIST of all the TalentSkillNames and then in the Talents entity simply have a numeric value which points to the PLIST version.

Thanks.

I've added a diagram which I believe is what you're meant to do, but I am unsure if this is correct.

[image: Entity]

Comment: I think AbilityCategories should have a to-many relationship with Abilities in the scenario you've described. Also, the convention is usually to name the Entities in the singular, i.e. Person, Ability, AbilityCategory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that you have a third entity, `Skill`. This can have a one to many relationship with `Talent`, which then just has the level as an attribute.

Effectively, this means you are modelling a many-to-many relationship between `Staff` and `Talent` through the `Skill` entity. Logically, that seems to fit with the situation you're describing.

Comment: Would this also work for say `Article` -< `Category` Where you don't want to keep repeating the category name?  Thanks.

Comment: For a relationship like Article and Category, I'd probably make it a to-many both ways (i.e. and Article can have many Categories, and a Category can have many Articles). This is straightforward to model in Core Data.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've added a diagram which I believe is what you mean to the main question thread.